# Regular expression: excluding some strings but including others

Tags: regex

I have this link:

```
http://anthropology.school.com/stuff/anthropology.999.ug.courses
```

What's the regular expression to exclude every link that contains `/stuff/` but still include the ones that contain `999.ug.courses` (even though `/stuff/` is included)

So for example, the link above would be okay because it contains both `999.ug.courses` and `/stuff/`

I just don't want the ones that ONLY contain `/stuff/` in the link.

Also, I'm writing this in a simple configuration text file in an open source I'm using.

samples:

`^http://([a-zA-Z0-9]*\.)*school.com/`

`^(file|ftp|mailto):`

`\.gif|GIF|jpg|com|JPG|js|png|php|PNG|pp|ico|atom|ICO|css|sit|eps|wmf|zip|ppt|mpg|xls|gz|rpm|tgz|mov|MOV|py|exe|pdf|jpeg|JPEG|bmp|BMP)$`

`[?*!@=]`

`(/about|/giving|/admissions|/Admissions|/studyabroad|/summer|/spring.in.ny|/winter|/academics|/life|/research|/global|/footer|/content|/AZ|/registrar|/its|/shc|/999|/explore.school|/prehealth|/eve|/people|/events|/IAA|sca|/aboutus|/subfields|/specialprograms|/newsevents|/resources|/employment)`

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post more example URLs? Do you always only want URLs with the "999.ug.courses" part?

Answer (score 2):

If those are the only things you need to match for, this regex should do (in Perl format):

```
/http:\/\/anthropology.school.com(\/\w+\/(?<!\/stuff\/)\w*)|(\/stuff\/anthropology\.999\.ug\.courses)/
```

It first matches the beginning of the URL, then either a directory named anything but *stuff* or */stuff/anthropology.999.ug.courses*.

Comment: Actually I have to have it so that the beginning starts with a minus sign to signal exclusion. Let's say I only gave you this: -/stuff/anthropology.999.ug.courses That basically says to exclude /stuff/anthropology.999.ug.courses I want it so that any link with ONLY /stuff/ is left out. But if it has /stuff/ together with 999.ug.courses in the link, then I have my answer. The thing is, I have to use a minus (-) sign in front of the expression. Thanks

Comment: Make sure you escape the dots in the domain so that they don't match random characters.

Comment: Good point Ates! I remembered them for the end part though... :)

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a single regexp? Can you do `!/\/stuff\// || /999.ug.courses/` ?

Comment: I don't think so. Here's a sample valid regex: +^http://([a-zA-Z0-9]*\.)*school.com/

Comment: Not sure what you mean. "Valid" in what sense?

Comment: I think Mike simply misunderstood your shorthand.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for conditional sub-pattern evaluation here. Following regex should work for you:

```
~.*?(999\.ug\.courses)(?(1).*?|(?<!/stuff/))~
```

Using php code:

```
preg_match('~.*?(999\.ug\.courses)(?(1).*?|(?<!/stuff/))~', $str, $m );
var_dump($m);
```

When I ran above code with:

```
$str ="http://anthropology.school.com/stuff/anthropology.999.ug.courses";
```

I got:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(64) "http://anthropology.school.com/stuff/anthropology.999.ug.courses"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "999.ug.courses"
}
```

But when I ran above code with (no `anthropology.999.ug.courses` in text):

```
$str ="http://anthropology.school.com/stuff/anthropology.888.ug.courses";
```

I got:

```
array(0) {
}
```

Here is the [live demo](http://ideone.com/lv4QT) of above code.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
preg_match('#^.+?/stuff/(?!.*999\.ug\.courses).*$#', $url));
```

Your desired URLs are the ones which *don't* match the regex.